# Understanding shadow maps in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to implement omni-directional shadow mapping by following [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Point-Shadows) from learnOpenGL, its idea is very simple: in the shadow pass, we're going to capture the scene from the light's perspective into a cubemap (shadow map), and we can use the geometry shader to build the depth cubemap with just one render pass. Here's the shader code for generating our shadow map:

vertex shader

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 model;

void main() {
    gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

geometry shader

```c
#version 330 core
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=18) out;

uniform mat4 shadowMatrices[6];
out vec4 FragPos; // FragPos from GS (output per emitvertex)

void main() {
    for (int face = 0; face < 6; ++face) {
        gl_Layer = face; // built-in variable that specifies to which face we render.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) // for each triangle vertex {
            FragPos = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            gl_Position = shadowMatrices[face] * FragPos;
            EmitVertex();
        }    
        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

fragment shader

```c
#version 330 core
in vec4 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float far_plane;

void main() {
    // get distance between fragment and light source
    float lightDistance = length(FragPos.xyz - lightPos);
    
    // map to [0;1] range by dividing by far_plane
    lightDistance = lightDistance / far_plane;
    
    // write this as modified depth
    gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
}
```

Compared to classic shadow mapping, the main difference here is that we are explicitly writing to the depth buffer, with **linear** depth values between 0.0 and 1.0. Using this code I can correctly cast shadows in my own scene, but I cannot fully understand the fragment shader, and I think this code is flawed, here is why:

Image that we have 3 spheres sitting on a floor, and a point light above the spheres. Looking down the floor from the point light, we can see the `-z` slice of the shadow map: (in RenderDoc textures are displayed bottom up, sorry for that).

[image]

If we write `gl_FragDepth = lightDistance` in the fragment shader, we are manually updating the depth buffer so the hardware cannot perform the early z test, as a result, every fragment will go through our shader code to update the depth buffer, no fragment is discarded early to save performance. Now what if we draw the floor after the spheres?

The sphere fragments will write to the depth buffer first (per sample), followed by the floor fragments, but since the floor is farther away from the point light, it will overwrite the depth values of the sphere with larger values, and the shadow map will be incorrect. In this case, the order of drawing is important, distant objects must be drawn first, but it's not always possible to sort depth values for complex geometry. Perhaps we need something like order-independent transparency here?

To make sure that only the closest depth values are written to the shadow map, I modified the fragment shader a little bit:

```c
// solution 1
gl_FragDepth = min(gl_FragDepth, lightDistance);

// solution 2
if (lightDistance < gl_FragDepth) {
    gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
}

// solution 3
gl_FragDepth = 1.0;
gl_FragDepth = min(gl_FragDepth, lightDistance);
```

However, according to the OpenGL specification, none of them is going to work. Solution 2 cannot work because, if we were to update `gl_FragDepth` manually, we must update it in all execution paths. As for solution 1, when we clear the depth buffer using `glClearNamedFramebufferfv(id, GL_DEPTH, 0, &clear_depth)`, the depth buffer will be filled with value `clear_depth`, which is usually 1.0, but the default value of `gl_FragDepth` variable is not the same as `clear_depth`, it is actually undefined, so could be anything between 0 and 1. On my driver the default value is 0, so `gl_FragDepth = min(0.0, lightDistance)` is 0, the shadow map will be completely black. Solution 3 also won't work because we are still overwriting the previous depth value.

I learned that for OpenGL 4.2 and above, we can enforce the early z test by redeclaring the `gl_FragDepth` variable using:
`layout (depth_<condition>) out float gl_FragDepth;`
since my depth comparision function is the default `glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)`, the condition needs to be `depth_greater` in order for the hardware to do early z. Unfortunately, this also won't work as we are writing linear depth values to the buffer, which are always less than the default non-linear depth value `gl_FragCoord.z`, so the condition is really `depth_less`. Now I'm completely stuck, the depth buffer seems to be way more difficult than I thought.

Where might my reasoning be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> The sphere fragments will write to the depth buffer first (per sample),
> followed by the floor fragments, but since the floor is farther away from the
> point light, it will overwrite the depth values of the sphere with larger
> values, and the shadow map will be incorrect.

But if your fragment shader is not using early depth tests, then the hardware will perform depth testing *after* the fragment shader has executed.

From the OpenGL 4.6 specification, section 14.9.4:

> When...the active program was linked with early fragment tests disabled,
> these operations [including depth buffer test] are performed only after
> fragment program execution

So if you write to gl_FragDepth in the fragment shader, the hardware cannot take advantage of the speed gain of early depth testing, as you said, but that doesn't mean that depth testing *won't* occur. So long as you are using GL_LESS or GL_LEQUAL for the depth test, objects that are further away won't obscure objects that are closer.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize the depth testing is performed after fragment execution, so my worries are actually redundant. However, I also find that writing to `gl_FragDepth` is a bad idea and should be avoided as much as possible, so I ended up writing depth values to the RGBA color buffer instead, now I can still take advantage of early z.